# Does the repaint() method in Java require a timer or action?

Tags: java, animation, methods, paintcomponent, repaint

I've been working on a small "game," which I think is called Pachinko. I have uploaded an image of what the game screen looks like. I will be dropping balls, and having them look like they are rolling off pegs, ending up being caught in the bottom "gates."

My problem is that I cannot get the `repaint()` method to work. Does the `repaint()` method require a timer, or action to work? Please look at at these two classes. I have created a `Ball` class object inside the `GameWindow` class (near the bottom), and would like to update the ball's `x`/`y` values using the `Ball`'s `setPos()` method, then repaint, so the ball appears to move.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need an `update()` method to use the `repaint()` method?

Game Window Image:

[image: Game Window Image]

```
public class GameWindow extends JPanel{

    private int numBalls = 0;

    // GameWindow Constructor (Sets Ball amount from user)
    public GameWindow(int balls){

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Game Window");
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Globally set ball amount
        setBallAmount(balls);

        myFrame.add(this);  

        myFrame.setSize(325, 790);
        myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        myFrame.setResizable(false);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

    } // End GameWindow Constructor

    // Function setPegAmount;
    // Passes the amount of balls the user to class variable.
    public void setBallAmount(int balls)
    {
        numBalls = balls * 2;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g); // housekeeping, etc.
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE); // Background

        int counter = 0; // count what number peg we are painting
        int row = 1;     // calculate what row we are creating
        int rowSpacer = 55;
        boolean evenRow = false;
        int columnSpacer = 60;

        // DRAW PEGS TO SCREEN (4 rows of 8, 4 rows of 7)
        for (int x = 0; x < 60; x++)
        {
            // For odd rows
            if (row % 2 == 1)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillOval(rowSpacer - 40, columnSpacer, 10, 10);
                rowSpacer += 40;
                counter++;
            }
            // For Even rows
            else 
            {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillOval(rowSpacer - 20, columnSpacer, 10, 10);
                rowSpacer += 40;
                counter++;
            }

            // Check to see if we are finished with odd row
            if (counter % 8 == 0 && evenRow == false)
            {
                row++;
                rowSpacer = 55;
                columnSpacer += 60;
                evenRow = true;
                counter = 0;
            }
            else if(counter % 7 == 0 && evenRow == true) 
            {
                row++;
                rowSpacer = 55;
                columnSpacer += 60;
                evenRow = false;
                counter = 0;
            }
        } // END DRAWING PEGS TO SCREEN

        // DRAW RECTANGULAR WALLS TO SCREEN
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    // Wall Color
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 5, 760);   // LEFT Wall
        g.fillRect(315, 0, 5, 760); // RIGHT Wall
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 315, 5);   // TOP Wall
        g.fillRect(0, 755, 320, 5); // BOTTOM Wall

        // DRAW BOTTOM GATES
        int gateSeperator = 35;
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(gateSeperator, 500, 10, 255);
            gateSeperator += 40;
        }

        // Create instance of ball object
        Ball myBall = new Ball();

        // Test draw ball
        myBall.drawBall(g);    // The ball is drawn to screen
        myBall.setPos(50, 50); // Change the x and y coordinates of the Ball

        repaint(); // Also tried "this.repaint();" but neither does anything


    } // Ends paintComponent

} // End GameWindow Class
```

Ball.java:

```
public class Ball{

    private int x = 5;
    private int y = 30;

    public void setPos(int xPos, int yPos)
    {
        x = xPos;
        y = yPos;
    }

    public void drawBall(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);

    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify pantComponent: it's purpose is to render a current snapshot of your game state and nothing else. The logic (updated of game state) have to be placed elsewhere. After you update the state then you need to call repaint. Repaint just marks object to be painted which happens later in EDT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's the way to do it. Swing's not my specialty but calling `repaint` in `paintComponent`, according to my experience, is incorrect.

For example, tell the component to `repaint` itself.

```
/**
 * Tells the view to repaint itself.
 */
public void update() {
    repaint();
}
```

[As soon as possible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()), `repaint` ends up calling `paintComponent` via `paint`.

```
/**
 * Paints the component.
 * @param g The graphics object for the view.
 */
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // Draw some stuff...
}
```

So calling `repaint` inside of `paintComponent`is likely not what you're wanting to do. What you should be doing is using `repaint` to invode `paintComponent`.

I don't think you can rely on putting the `repaint` or `update` at the end of `paintComponent` because, I believe, multiple calls to `repaint` get lumped into a single `update`. So, yes, to properly animate object you should look into using a Swing `Timer`. For example,

```
Timer timer = Timer(delay, action);
timer.start();
```

The above timer will invoke the given action on the delay given in milliseconds. Please see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for more details.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a little over my head. There isn't a simple way to get my Ball object to be updated to it's new location? If possible, can you use my code in the answer?

Comment: @FoxDonut, OK, that makes sense. Sorry about that. I stripped it out to make sure it was relative. I'll delete the commentary then...

Comment: So i do, indeed, need an update method. I'm trying to get this darn ball to move and it won't budge still.

Comment: @FoxDonut, in short yes; but you also have to look at using a timer to update the view. So, I don't think that you can put a `repaint` at the end of `paintComponent` to make an infinite loop that will animate it. You should look into a Swing `Timer` which can have an action triggered which would be the mechanism that invokes the updates.

Comment: I think that answers my initial question. I added the update method outside of paintComponent, exactly as you have shown me, and it does not activate, because i do not have a timer. I think i'm getting this now. I like that you stated how it would infinitely loop without the timer, which just adds more to the answer.

So, now i basically have to have a timer, that once it his a specific millisecond, will call update(). Is this correct?

Comment: @FoxDonut, see my edit at the bottom of the post. Yes, and this introduces another aspect as you'll need to implement an [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html).